# Text is pushing DIV below

Tags: html, css

My text is pushing div element that contains them below.

```css
slidepassos{
 position: relative;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
float: left;
margin-top: -1px;

}

#anchorHow{
 margin-top: 65px;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}


.swipe {
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.swipe-wrap{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.swipe-wrap > div {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.passo-um{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000101;
}

.passoumback{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url("../img/passoumu.jpg");
 background-position: top center;
}

.passoumgrad{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,37,63,0.7);

}

.passo-um h1{
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}

.passo-um h2{
 color: #EBAC00;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 53px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 35%;
}

.passo-um p{
 color: white;
 padding: 18px 8%;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 23px;
 float: left;
}

.passoumilu {
 width: 300px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 9%;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.swipeleftcontent{
 z-index: 1;
 background-size: 60px 60px;
 margin-left: 157px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 14%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidepassos" class="swipe slidepassos">
 <div class="swipe-wrap">
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="passo-um">
   <h1>How?</h1>
   <h2>Step 1:</h2>
   <img src="img/passoumilu.svg" class="passoumilu">
   <p>Do your coach oriented WOD. Remember, know your limits and try to break them.</p>
     <div class="passoumback">
      <div class="passoumgrad"></div>
     </div>
    <img src="img/swipeleft.png" class="swipeleftcontent">
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

image showing the text on top of the DIV instead inside it.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPReR.png)

Ive tried to mess with the floats, and inline-blocks, but nothing affects it. Dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Well, it's showing right inside "div.passo-um". Where'd you expect it to be?

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski Inside the DIV that contains the Image. If i use float in the h1, the text gets inside, but then i cant align center...